# Why are the non-diagonals in a Jacobian zeros?

Tags: matrix-calculus, jacobian

From the [Matrix Calculus for Deep Learning](https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/index.html), in the "***Derivatives of vector element-wise binary operators***" section, it says

> Any time the general function is a vector, we know that $f_i(w)$ reduces to $f_i(w_i) = w_i$.

[image]

**Why is it that $f_i(w)$ reduces to $f_i(w_i) = w_i$ for $y=w+x$ ?**

**Can someone show an example of why when `i != j`, the partial derivatives are zero?**

---

Is this answer satisfactory? Something like this?

$\frac{d}{dw_i}f_i(w_j)$ when `i != j`, the scalar derivative is 0

Comment: In the quoted passage I don't see anything about $i\neq j.$ It's $w_i$ and $x_i.$ Also, the passage assumes at the start that $f(\mathbf w) = \mathbf w,$ so that simplifies a lot of things right away.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the off-diagonal elements are 0 is because the derivative of a constant is 0.  The key bit is that $w_i$ looks like a constant if we take the derivative with respect to $w_j$ for $j \ne i$.

Here is more of the [matrix calculus article](https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/index.html) I co-authored:

[image]